# How to Display the Contents of a text file in a TextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jfilechooser

How do you display the contents of a text file in a TextArea when your using JFileChooser.

Comment: Please do have a look at the latest edit :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I am assuming you want to add the JTextArea to the JFileChooser so that it can act like a file preview panel.

You can add a JTextArea to the JFileChooser by using the [setAccessory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAccessory%28javax.swing.JComponent%29) method.

This [tutorial on JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) shows how to do something similar where the accessory displays an image from the file rather than text from the file.

You will need to be careful to deal properly with files that don't contain text, or which are too large, or which cannot be opened due to permission, etc.  It will take a good bit of effort to get it right.

Comment: I liked this answer, as this had given me direction, since before that I misunderstood the whole thing :-)

Answer (score 2):

- You have to read official Oracle's [JTextArea tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
- Especially method [JTextArea.read(fileSelectedFromJFileChooser)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) , maybe right way in this case
- Please have a look at Reading, [Writing and Creating Files Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Here find one example program, for your help, though if the file to be read is long, then always take the help of [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ReadFileExample
{
    private BufferedReader input;
    private String line;
    private JFileChooser fc;

    public ReadFileExample()
    {
        line = new String();
        fc = new JFileChooser();        
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Read File Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JTextArea tarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);      

        JButton readButton = new JButton("OPEN FILE");
        readButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);

                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    //This is where a real application would open the file.
                    try
                    {
                        input = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream(
                                file)));
                        tarea.read(input, "READING FILE :-)");      
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {       
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Operation is CANCELLED :(");
                }
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(tarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(readButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ReadFileExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do have a look at Point 2, I doubt, what I edited as a link, is the right one or not !!